# How can I merge 2 mounted volumes on Debian 10?

Tags: merge, debian, storage, vps, mounted-volumes

I've got 2 volumes already mounted on a VPS from Hetzner.

The first one is on / with 1To space. The other one on /home with 2To space.

I want to get my 3 To together, how can I manage to merge those 2 volumes without erasing any data ?

Here is a picture of what a `df -h` looks like :

[image: df -h]

Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge them using a union filesystem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS

In Linux, you can find several kernel modules implementing a union fileystem such as aufs and overlayfs. Available modules may vary depending on kernel configuration in your vps. I will give you a configuration example using the aufs kernel module.

In first, create a subdirectory for each mount point:

```
mkdir -p /for-aufs
mkdir -p /home/for-aufs
```

To continue, create a directory for the aufs mount point:

```
mkdir -p /aufs
```

Edit your /etc/fstab file

```
none /aufs aufs br:/for-aufs=rw:/home/for-aufs=rw,sum,create=rr 0 0
```

Or using mount directly:

```
mount -t aufs -o br:/for-aufs=rw:/home/for-aufs=rw,sum,create=rr none /aufs
```

Then, you will see a new mount point in `/aufs` linked to `/for-aufs` (/dev/md2) and `/home/for-aufs` (/dev/md3) when executing `df -h`. When you are using `/aufs` mount point, a round-robing policy will create/modify files between `/for-aufs` and `/home/for-aufs`.

In conclusion, `/for-aufs` + `/home/for-aufs` = `/aufs`

Remember to read the manual for more information:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/aufs.5.html